# How do I create an HTML variable

Tags: html, variables, widget

I am working on an HTML widget, and I need to know if it is possible to create a purely HTML variable, or do  have to embed java or javascript code inside the HTML code, and then create the variable in that language.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need an HTML variable?

Comment: because I can't make my embeded javascript work. I think my website builder only likes HTML

Comment: I think your problem is not making an HTML variable, it's enabling your JS in your specific browser.

Comment: it's possible that I am embedding the code wrong. How would you embed javascript in HTML?

Comment: <html> <script type = "javascript"> var hello = "hello" </script> </html>

Comment: I tried something similar, and it didn't work. Here is what I tried:     <script type = "javascript"> text(testing,0,0)</script>

Comment: Well, try to enable your JS in your browser first?